# How can I dynamically change the URL of my React app when I toggle between languages?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

**I am new to React.**

I have made a React app where the user has the ability to change the language of the content.

If you change the language while on the landingpage ( ../ ) it renders the toggled language just fine, but on all the other URLs (i.e ../About) I get a 404 when toggling the language.

The NAV menu still changes language correctly, and when clicking the link in the NAV menu of the content that was supposed to render when the language was toggled, if renders just fine.

After this, all links and content work fine as long as I don't toggle the language.

As it is now, I need to go to the landingpage every time I want to toggle the language to avoid getting a 404.

What I want is to be able to toggle the language regardless of what content is rendered and regardless of what URL I am on.

*I do realize that the URL is not updating like I want it to, I just can't figure out how to do it.*

I am using HashRouter because my app is currently on GH pages.

**My React app:**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

import { HashRouter, NavLink, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

import { Home } from './pages/Home';
import { About } from './pages/About';
import { Projects } from './pages/Projects';
import { Project } from './pages/Project';
import { Contact } from './pages/Contact';
import { PageNotFound } from './pages/PageNotFound';
import { ProjectsMenu } from './pages/ProjectsMenu';

import { Hjem } from './pages/Hjem';
import { Om } from './pages/Om';
import { Prosjekter } from './pages/Prosjekter';
import { Prosjekt } from './pages/Prosjekt';
import { Kontakt } from './pages/Kontakt';
import { SideIkkeFunnet } from './pages/SideIkkeFunnet';
import { ProsjekterMeny } from './pages/ProsjekterMeny';

import './assets/App.css';

function App() {
  const [isDarkMode, setIsDarkMode] = useState(false);
  const [language, setLanguage] = useState('english');

  const handleModeToggle = () => {
    setIsDarkMode(!isDarkMode);
  };

  const handleLanguageToggle = () => {
    setLanguage(language === 'english' ? 'norwegian' : 'english');
  };

  const getRoutes = () => {
    if (language === 'english') {
      return (
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="/About" element={<About />} />
          <Route path="/Projects" element={<ProjectsMenu />}>
            <Route index element={<Projects />} />
            <Route path=":id" element={<Project />} />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/Contact" element={<Contact />} />
          <Route path="*" element={<PageNotFound />} />
        </Routes>
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Hjem />} />
          <Route path="/Om" element={<Om />} />
          <Route path="/Prosjekter" element={<ProsjekterMeny />}>
            <Route index element={<Prosjekter />} />
            <Route path=":id" element={<Prosjekt />} />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/Kontakt" element={<Kontakt />} />
          <Route path="*" element={<SideIkkeFunnet />} />
        </Routes>
      );
    }
  };

  return (
    <HashRouter>
      <div className={`app ${isDarkMode ? 'dark-mode' : 'light-mode'}`}>
        <nav>
          <div id="toggle" className="displayMode" onClick={handleModeToggle}>
            {`${isDarkMode ? 'Light Mode' : 'Dark Mode'}`}
          </div>
          <div id="language-toggle" className="languageMode" onClick={handleLanguageToggle}>
            {language === 'english' ? 'Norsk' : 'English'}
          </div>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <NavLink to="/">{language === 'english' ? 'Home' : 'Hjem'}</NavLink>
            </li>
            <li>
              <NavLink to={language === 'english' ? 'About' : 'Om'}>{language === 'english' ? 'About' : 'Om'}</NavLink>
            </li>
            <li>
              <NavLink to={language === 'english' ? 'Projects' : 'Prosjekter'}>{language === 'english' ? 'Projects' : 'Prosjekter'}</NavLink>
            </li>
            <li>
              <NavLink to={language === 'english' ? 'Contact' : 'Kontakt'}>{language === 'english' ? 'Contact' : 'Kontakt'}</NavLink>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
        <div className="homeAnimation"></div>
        {getRoutes()}
      </div>
    </HashRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I have tried to use both if-statements and ternaries to force the URL to update to the other language (I have ofc made components for the other language), but it still doesn't change the URL immediately when the language is toggled, at least not in my Edge or Chrome browsers.

I also tried using Switch and Redirect, but found out that they are not compatible with HashRouter.

> Can anyone please explain to me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Do you actually *need* to translate the URL into another language? What you are trying to do isn't very sustainable as the app grows. The basic issue is that you need to also translate/map the current URL path into the new language ***and redirect to it***. You are also duplicating each component in each language which isn't ***DRY*** at all. Better to use a localization library to "inject" localized strings and use a single routes and component structure. You could make the language part of the URL, e.g. like `"/en/about"` or `"/about?language=en"` and render the localized string values.

Comment: Thank you Drew, you brought up some very valid points for my first React app. I have restructured my code to use a localization library instead, and removed all the unnecessary translated components. As for the URL, I will research your suggestions and find a more suitable solution for my app.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to put the `/` in your links here, for example:

```
<li>
 <NavLink to={language === 'english' ? 'About' : 'Om'}>{languag ==='english' ? 'About' : 'Om'}</NavLink>
</li>
```

try this for all routes you have:

```
<li>
 <NavLink to={language === 'english' ? '/About' : '/Om'}>{languag ==='english' ? 'About' : 'Om'}</NavLink>
</li>
```

for Home is ok!!!

Comment: Just to be sure, I tried your suggested edits but they had no effect. I think React intuitively knows to put a `/` in front of the path names.